# Longman dictionary in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dictionary

After installing Longman dictionary I had a permission error, then I changed owner and file permissions. Now when I click on desktop icon I get:

`There was an error launching the application.`

When I open with root in terminal I get:

```
root@DEMON:~/ldoce5#  ./ldoce5
./ldoce5-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libpangoxft-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
```

while I have `libpangoxft-1.0-0`

Comment: What's the output of `LC_MESSAGES=C ldd ~/ldoce5/ldoce5-bin | grep -iFe 'not found'`?

Answer (score 1):

The following commands have worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```